# How is a static method returning a object of its own abstract class - WebRequest

Tags: c#

While working on the WebRequest class I noticed that it is an abstract class, and it has a create method which is returning a object of the abstract class.

I have read that abstract class cannot be instantiated, so i'm trying to understand how the static method is returning the object

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(URl);
```

Create Method definition:

```
public static WebRequest Create(string requestUriString);
```

See [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Net.WebRequest);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8)

i tried this, and as expected got an error

```
abstract class Test
    {
        public static Test Runmachine()
        {
            return new Test();

        }
    }
```

Comment: It returns an instance of a type that **inherits** `WebRequest`.

Comment: From the very page you linked to. Because the WebRequest class is an abstract class, the actual behavior of WebRequest instances at run time is determined by the descendant class returned by Create method

Comment: Take a look at the source code [on github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Requests/src/System/Net/WebRequest.cs). It more like `public static WebRequest Create() { return new HttpWebRequest(); }`

Comment: The signature says it returns `WebRequest` but it returns an instance of `HttpWebRequest` as @Kalten points out. `HttpWebRequest` is a specialization of `WebRequest`.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen and others - Thank you all for the helpful comments, i now understand it very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and see for yourself. You can return a more specialized, non-abstract version of the same class, e.g. a class that derives from `Test`.

```
abstract class Test
{
    public static Test RunMachine()
    {
        return new SpecializedTest();
    }
}

class SpecializedTest : Test {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you have missed, is Polymorphism.If you have a base class A and a derived class B, any object of type B, is also of type A. In other words any object of type B can be assigned to a variable of type A. In your case, the return type of the method being WebRequest, doesn't mean that the returned object is a direct instance of WebRequest. It can -and since WebRequest is abstract, it has to- be an instance of a derived class.